# Correct writing of a transpose, or inverse, of a matrix that is function of variables

Tags: matrices, notation

What would be more correct to write, i.e. if there is any difference, between:

$$
B=A(x,y,z)^{-1} \tag 1
$$

$$
B=A^{-1}(x,y,z) \tag 2
$$
Same question goes for matrix transpose, conjugate transpose, and other operations symbolized using exponents.

I think, though, that both may be confusing. Equation $(1)$ may be seen as the product of matrix $A$ with the inverse of a matrix formed by vectors $x, y, z$. Equation $(2)$ may be seen as the product of the inverse of matrix $A$ with a matrix formed by vectors $x, y, z$.

But supposedly we know that $A$ is a matrix function of variables $x,y,z$, then what would be the preferred notation?

Answer (score 1):

As someone who is a matrix theorist, my preference would be for equation (1).

There are other options available. For instance, you could also write $$A_{xyz}^{-1}.$$

If the variables never change, you can make a convention that $A$ is a matrix-valued function depending on the variables $x$, $y$, and $z$ and then drop the variables à la 
$$ A = A(x,y,z)$$
and then simply refer to the matrix $A$.

Lastly, set $M= A(x,y,z)$. If this matrix is invertible, then you can simply refer to $M^{-1}$.

Although there are many-agreed upon notational conventions, often we're required to come up with our own on-the-fly. The key is deriving a notational system that minimizes ambiguity and maximizes clarity and neatness of exposition.

Comment: why would you prefer (1) to (2)? Do you know if there is a notation convention for this specific case?